# json data from server is not displayed in listview

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to retrieve data from server and display it in listview. But when I compile this it is not working and the list is even not showing in the activity.

Mylist.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <AbsoluteLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edItem"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edUnit"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edPrice"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"

            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edDisc"

            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
     </AbsoluteLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Content_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:context="com.example.user.merchant.MainActivity"
   tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp">
  </ListView>



  <SearchView
     android:id="@+id/search_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   </SearchView> 
   </RelativeLayout>
```

AppController.java

```
     public class AppController extends Application {

     public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

     private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
     // private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
   }

   public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
     return mInstance;
   }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
      if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
      }

    return mRequestQueue;
   }


    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
      req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
      if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
       }
    }
  }
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
  public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
 private Activity activity;
CustomFilter filter;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<InventoryModel> InventoryModelItems;
private List<InventoryModel> filterList;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<InventoryModel> InventoryModelItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.InventoryModelItems = InventoryModelItems;
    this.filterList=InventoryModelItems;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {

    return InventoryModelItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return InventoryModelItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);


    TextView ItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edItem);
    TextView Unit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edUnit);
    TextView Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edPrice);
    TextView Discount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edDisc);

    // getting InventoryModel data for the row
    InventoryModel m = InventoryModelItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image


    // title
    ItemName.setText(m.getItemName());

    // rating
    Unit.setText("Unit: " + (m.getUnit()));


    // release year
    Price.setText("Rs: " + String.valueOf(m.getPrice()));
    Discount.setText("Discount: " + String.valueOf(m.getUnit()));
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter==null)
    {
        filter=new CustomFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}
class CustomFilter extends Filter
{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        if(constraint != null&&constraint.length()>0)
        {
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            ArrayList<InventoryModel> filters=new ArrayList<InventoryModel>();

            for(int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++)
            {
                if(filterList.get(i).getItemName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                    InventoryModel p= new InventoryModel(filterList.get(i).getItemName(),filterList.get(i).getUnit(),filterList.get(i).getPrice(),filterList.get(i).getDiscount());
                    filters.add(p);
                }
            }
            results.count=filters.size();
            results.values=filters;

        }
        else
        {
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        InventoryModelItems=(List<InventoryModel>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
    }


 }
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String url = "url";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<InventoryModel> InventoryModelList = new ArrayList<InventoryModel>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
public TextView test;
SearchView inputSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, InventoryModelList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow);
    //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow));
   // test=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.listtest);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
    JsonArrayRequest InventoryModelReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                   // test.setText(response);
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            InventoryModel InventoryModel = new InventoryModel();
                            InventoryModel.setItemName(obj.getString("Item_Name"));
                            InventoryModel.setUnit(obj.getString("Unit"));
                            InventoryModel.setPrice(((Number) obj.get("Price"))
                                    .floatValue());
                            InventoryModel.setDiscount(((Number) obj.get("Discount")).floatValue());

                            // adding InventoryModel to InventoryModels array
                            InventoryModelList.add(InventoryModel);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(InventoryModelReq);




   /* toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intenthome = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intenthome);

        }
    });*/


   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intentfloat = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemAdd.class);
                    startActivity(intentfloat);
                }
            });


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            //toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();



            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }







        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if(id == R.id.account) {
                Intent intentaccount = new Intent(MainActivity.this, account.class);
                startActivity(intentaccount);

            }
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            if(id==R.id.action_notify) {
                Intent intentNotify = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notification.class);
                startActivity(intentNotify);
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_processing) {
                // Handle the camera action
                Intent intentProcessing = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProcessingItem.class);
                startActivity(intentProcessing);
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_processed) {
                Intent intentProcessed = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProcessedItem.class);
                startActivity(intentProcessed);

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_Aborted) {
                Intent intentAborted = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AbortedIem.class);
                startActivity(intentAborted);

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_delivery) {
                Intent intentDelivered = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeliveredItem.class);
                startActivity(intentDelivered);

            }
            else if (id == R.id.logout)

            {
                // private void logout(){
                //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                //Getting out sharedpreferences
                                    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                //Getting editor
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                //Puting the value false for loggedin
                                    editor.putBoolean(config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                //Putting blank value to email
                                    editor.putString(config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "");

                //Saving the sharedpreferences
                                    editor.commit();

                //Starting login activity
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivityMerchant.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                }
                            });

                //Showing the alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }




             else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You should not be using "AbsoluteLayout". It's deprecated since API level 3.

Comment: its not working..list is not displayed in the main activity. cant identify what the actual problem is...

Comment: actually, i want to fetch data from server and want to display it into the android listview. for this i already set that mylist.xml and define listview in content.xml. json results is correctly displayed in browser, but it is not displayed in the listiew.and even i couldnt find the listview in the activity as well